# Android - Intent manage. Old intent is resend if user open application from task-manager

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a problem. When i call `finish()` method activity still hold in task-manager, and if user restart it from task-manager my activity receive old intent. If that intent was sent from push-notification I have unwanted reaction: my app start process intent with push-notification data.

How correctly manage push-notification intent behavior in my activity for avoid wrong activity state?

My app receive a push-notification and form pending intent for reaction on push:

```
       final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int defaultOptions = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        defaultOptions |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        Intent intentAction = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intentAction.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intentAction.putExtra(BUNDLE_COLLAPSE_KEY, data.getString(BUNDLE_COLLAPSE_KEY));
        intentAction.setAction(CUSTOM_ACTION);

        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        int notificationFlags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        final Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_splash)
                .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(data.getString(BUNDLE_PUSH_CONTENT_DATA))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(defaultOptions)
                .getNotification();
        notification.flags |= notificationFlags;
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

after user came in app from push, application, obviously, receive intent with `CUSTOM_ACTION` and do some work:

```
private void intentProcess(Intent intent) {
    boolean customAction = intent.getAction().equals(GCMPushReceiver.CUSTOM_ACTION);
    if (customAction) {
        //push reaction, do some staff with intent
    } else {
        //no push reaction, user just open activity
    }
}
```

I call `intentProcess` method from `onCreate` and from `onNewIntent`:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
//this case if my app closed and user tap on push
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /* ... */
        intentProcess(getIntent());
    }
//this case if my app opened and user tap on push
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        intentProcess(intent);
    }
}
```

Activity declaration in manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: did you find solution to this ?

Comment: @Shena, I don't remember, it was very long time ago=) But, if you face same problem I may check it.

Comment: it's old, but have you tested on differents devices? Same issue?

Comment: I think this could probably help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116110/clearing-intent

Answer (score 1):

Try to Use this

```
int id= NotificationID.getID();
final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, intentAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// rest of your code 

notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
```

Add a new class

```
    public class NotificationID {

    /**
     * An AtomicInteger is used in applications such as atomically incremented
     * counters, and cannot be used as a replacement for an Integer. However,
     * this class does extend Number to allow uniform access by tools and
     * utilities that deal with numerically-based classes.
     */
    private final static AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger(0);

    /**
     * Method to the automatically incremented int value.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public static int getID() {
        return c.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

Every time the notification generated it creates new intent with different id.

If you don't want your activity display/added to task manager add these lines in activity tag of AndroidManifest.

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
android:noHistory="true"
```