# How to clear an intent in Cordova after window.location.reload

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-intent, cordova-plugins

My Cordova app uses:

An intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

A plugin to handle the intent: 
https://github.com/napolitano/cordova-plugin-intent

It works well. However, in some cases my app needs to reload the current location with window.location.reload().
In this case the latest intent is "called" again. But it should be handeled just ones.

I'm aware of [Clearing intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116110/clearing-intent)

Is there a way to mark an intent as "handeled" in Javascript (that is, without changing the plugin) so that after window.location.reload() the intent is not handled again?